# I am prevented from creating a next app by my PC

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli, solana-pay, nextjs

Gm frens, I tried creating a next js project and I kept getting this error " Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\solana-pay-store'", something about me not having permission to create that file

Has anyone ever encountered this? and if you did, how did you solve it?

Comment: This problem isn't related to Solana but is a Windows limitation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing isn't related to Solana but is a Windows limitation.

Windows doesn't let you create a directory a directory in `C:\Windows`. If you try creating it on your desktop it will work.